# Probability of sequence for given rate constants

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, polymers

Consider a copolymer, $C_{r,s}^A$ containing $r$ number of $A$ monomers and $s$ number of $B$ monomers with $A$ at the reactive end of the polymer. The equilibrium constant for $A$-$A$, $A$-$B$, $B$-$A$, and $B$-$B$ bonds are $K_{AA}$, $K_{AB}$, $K_{BA}$ and $K_{BB}$ respectively.

$K_{AA} = exp(-\beta * \Delta g_{AA})$, where $\Delta g_{AA}$ is free energy change of $A$-$A$ bond formed. other equilibrium constants are also defined in similar way.

$C_{r,s}^A$ = A-------------

Hence, I am interested in following quantities: $\mathsf P(AB)$ (probability of sequence $AB$) and $\mathsf P(AA)$ (probability of sequence $AA$).

Comment: Not sure what the "equilibrium constant" means in a molecule of fixed composition - I could understand an "energy" of a particular arrangement, and maybe there is a relationship between the two. Do you have any ideas about that? I would usually compute energy of each configuration, then use Boltzmann to give relative probability. Does that make sense?

Comment: i have edited question and defined equilibrium constant. hope its clear now.

Comment: That's helpful. One more clarification: you only care to know whether there is an A or a B next to the reactive end of the polymer, and not any of the rest (which I assume is a large number of groups, so we can assume that r~r-1 and s~s-1, right?)

Comment: yes. thats correct but just to emphasize that end monomer is known to us i.e. A in this case and we are interested in the next monomer given the equilibrium constant.